# How use async functions with node-pdfkit?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-pdfkit

I am trying to create a PDF file with [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org). I insert an image with like this:

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
var doc = new PDFDocument();

doc.image(some_image_as_buffer);
```

and it is working like expected. But now want the image be trimmed and I found [GraphicsMagick for node.js](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/). But the problem that I have is to make it work with PDFKit. `doc.image` expects a filename or a buffer, but since I already have a buffer I want to work with buffers (there is no file anywhere because the buffer comes directly from the database).

The trimming works like this:

```
var gm = require('gm');
gm(some_image_as_buffer, 'image.png')
  .trim()
  .toBuffer(function(err, trimmed_image_buffer) {
    // trimmed_image_buffer is correct,
    // but I can't put it to the document like this:
    doc.image(trimmed_image_buffer);
    // beacause I don't know which page and/or position
    // the doc is currently on, because of the asynchronous
    // nature of this callback.
  });
```

**UPDATE**:

For clarification: I want to be able to use the asynchronous trimmed image in the synchronous code for PDFKit. PDFKit only works synchronously and `gm` doesn't offer a synchronous interface.

**UPDATE2**:

```
var gm = require('gm');
gm(some_image_as_buffer, 'image.png')
  .trim()
  .toBuffer(function(err, trimmed_image_buffer) {
    // trimmed_image_buffer is correct,
    // but I can't put it to the document like this:
    doc.image(trimmed_image_buffer);
    // beacause I don't know which page and/or position
    // the doc is currently on, because of the asynchronous
    // nature of this callback.
  });
doc.text('some text');
// is not guaranteed to run after image is inserted
// and a couple of hundred lines more
```

After the last line in this example there are a lot more lines of code which add content to the PDF, but I don't want to put everything (couple of hundred lines) in one callback just because I need on asynchronous function to manipulate the image.

Is there any way to make this manipulation synchronous?

Comment: And what is your question exactly? Do you want to have more control over asynchronous flow or you want to use something different than `doc.image`? If the latter then I cannot help much without further investigation, if the first then some promise based solution should work pretty elegantly.

Comment: In the http://pdfkit.org/docs/guide.pdf (page 5) there seems to be a way to get hold of page numbers using buffered pages and bufferedpagerange.I am not sure if you have tried this already?

Comment: @artur grzesiak: What I want is, that I can trim the image and add it to the pdf in some synchronous way, because pdfkit doesn't work asynchronously

Comment: @harryy000: That is not the problem, I know how this works and use this technique to render page numbers, but what I want is, to make the asynchronous code of `gm` work with the synchronous code of `pdfkit`

Comment: I hope I am not sounding naive,but why not finish the processing image cropping for all images with gm module (storing them in an array] and then start of with the pdk related processing.

Comment: All synchronous code can be used asynchronously.  You just call the function that runs it in the future.  On the other hand, it is not possible to run asynchronous code synchronously.  @arturgrzesiak is the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### UPDATE_2

You basically ask for stopping execution of a code until some asynchronous operation has completed. **For sure** it is not possible in general case.

In case of `gm` module, it is not possible either. The `gm` module spawns a new process for executing a command (in your case *trim()*) and the API for spawning new processes is asynchronous in its very nature.

#### UPDATE

To make use of promise in your scenario:

```
var gm = require('gm'),
    Q = require('Q'),
    PDFDocument = require('pdfkit'),
    doc = new PDFDocument();

function getTrimmedImage(some_image_as_buffer){
  var deferred = Q.defer(); 
  gm(some_image_as_buffer, 'image.png')
  .trim()
  .toBuffer(function(err, trimmed_image_buffer) {
    if(err) { deferred.reject(err); }
    else { deferred.resolve(trimmed_image_buffer); }
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}

// here goes all manipulations before the trimmed image is inserted

getTrimmedImage(some_image_as_buffer).then(
  function(trimmed_image_buffer){
     doc.image(trimmed_image_buffer);

     // here goes all manipulations after the trimmed image is inserted

  }
);
```

---

As I wrote in the comment above, a promise based solution should work elegantly. I use [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), but any other promise library will do the job, as well.

One option would be to collect all resources of asynchronous nature before starting manipulating the pdf. Then you are guaranteed that no race condition occur, though it may slow down the whole process. I used a toy example to have it working in the browser environment, let me know if you have any problems converting it to your use case:

```js
function getAsyncResource(){
  
  var defer = Q.defer();
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    var result = "Some value: " + Date.now();
    console.log("Async resource resolved: " + result); 
    defer.resolve(result);
    }, Math.random() * 5000);
  
  
  return defer.promise;
  }

function someOperationThatNeedsAsyncResources(A, B, C){
  
  console.log("Have all resources: ", A, B, C);
  
  }

var A = getAsyncResource(),
    B = getAsyncResource(),
    C = getAsyncResource();

Q.all([A,B,C]).spread(someOperationThatNeedsAsyncResources);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.1.2/q.js"></script>
```

Other option would be to split the process into steps, like so:

```js
function getAsyncResource(value){
  
  var defer = Q.defer();
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    var result = "Some value: " + value;
    console.log("Async resource resolved: " + result); 
    defer.resolve(result);
    }, Math.random() * 5000);
  
  
  return defer.promise;
  }

function nextStep(resource){
   console.log("Next step: " + resource);
  }

var A = getAsyncResource("A"),
    B = getAsyncResource("B"),
    C = getAsyncResource("C");

A.then(nextStep)
 .then(function(){return B;})
 .then(nextStep)
 .then(function(){return C;})
 .then(nextStep);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/1.1.2/q.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, but how should this work with my example, if I see correctly, the asynchronous code is still running asynchronously, with the only difference, that I can now run some code after all asynchronous calls are finished. But what I want - since PDFKit works synchronous - is to make the code stop, until the asynchronous trimming of the image is finished

Comment: @jigfox I updated my answer to make it working in your scenario: first the image is trimmed, *then* it is inserted into the pdf-document. If it is not enough for you, then please provide more context and point out explicitly what it is wrong.

Comment: It is correct that the image is trimmed, and than added, but thats already the case without the promise and with my original code. What I need to accomplish, is that the asynchronous code is somehow synchronized, so I don't need to put the complete PDF generation happening after the image into one callback (please see my updated answer for more details)

Comment: @jigfox now I understand what you wanted to achieve -- a callback based solution is **the only way to go**, as `gm` runs `ImageMagick` as a background process.

Comment: With ES6 using await would be the best solution here